# Create mysql select - multiple parameters (some are unnecessary)

Tags: php, mysql, select

Let's asume I have following object in PHP:

```
class param{
 public $home; //set by another function
 public $user; //set by another function
 public function createRequest(){
//in this function I want to create mysql string with $home and $user
  $sql = "select * FROM table WHERE home =".$this->home." AND user=".$this->user;
  return $sql;
}
```

Problem is, that $home (or $user) could be empty string and in this case I want to include all homes (or users), not just columns, where home="" (or user="");

Do you have any suggestion how to do that? Or is this idea wrong? (I'm just beginner with PHP)

Comment: By the way you are missing your speech marks for mysql_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant, and we should be using PDO prepared statements... but for sake of example:

```
class param{
  public $home; //set by another function
  public $user; //set by another function
  public function createRequest(){
    //in this function I want to create mysql string with $home and $user
    $sql = "select * FROM table";
    if(strlen($this->home) || strlen($this->user)) {
      $sql .= " WHERE ";
      $and = array();
      if(strlen($this->home))
        $and[] = " home='".$this->home."' ";
      if(strlen($this->user))
        $and[] = " user='".$this->user."' "; 
      $sql .= implode(" AND ", $and);
    }
    return $sql;
  }
}
```

Example test output:

```
$p = new param;
echo $p->createRequest();
echo "<br>";

$p->home = "foo";
echo $p->createRequest();
echo "<br>";

$p->user = "bar";
echo $p->createRequest();
echo "<br>";

$p->home = "";
echo $p->createRequest();
```

Will yield:

```
select * FROM table
select * FROM table WHERE home='foo' 
select * FROM table WHERE home='foo' AND user='bar' 
select * FROM table WHERE user='bar'
```

Comment: Prepared statements don't make this any easier.

Comment: Coupled with `sprintf`, I've seen better solutions!

Comment: I think you mean to say he should be properly escaping the values - and prepared statements are one way to do that. But you can escape them without preparent statements (and you probably **should** in this answer)

Comment: But I don't know his driver or how he's connecting to the database :o

Comment: Either way, you have to build the `WHERE` clause dynamically, either with interpolated values or `?`.

Comment: yes, I didn't use the PDO statements, to make it simple, but thank you for your example

Comment: The lack of escaping should at least be pointed out in the answer. If it was my answer, I'd probably write the code as if the OP was using non-OO `mysqli_` functions, and include a comment at the end about it.

Comment: Feel free to append to answer

Comment: Maybe include in your set of examples what happens with ``user = "'; DROP TABLE `table`; SELECT '";``

Answer (score 0):

```
class param{
 public $home; //set by another function
 public $user; //set by another function
 public function createRequest(){
//in this function I want to create mysql string with $home and $user
    $ClauseArray = array(' 1 = 1 ');
    if ($this->home != '') $ClauseArray[] = " home = '".$this->home."' ";
    if ($this->user != '') $ClauseArray[] = " user = '".$this->user."' ";
    $sql = "select * FROM table WHERE ".implode('AND', $ClauseArray);
    return $sql;
}
```